# Debian package installation problems - Bus errors, dpkg post-installation exit status 135

Tags: debian, dependencies, upgrade, debian-squeeze

I tried to install curl support for php 5 on my debian squeeze machine and since I'm having problems.

After trying to install curl I got dependency issues which I tried to solve by removing what started the issues. From one thing came another and I'm currently looking at ~29 issues when I try to do an apt-get upgrade. These issues vary from unable to config, dependency and unable to remove errors.

I tried apt-get upgrade -f and installing packages using dpkg command.
I tried removing using purge and force. I manually removed stuff to try and fix it.
I tried running dpkg --configure -a.
I've to say I'm still pretty new to linux so I'm out of idea's and cant seem to find an answer online that matches my problems.

Here's a part of the apt-get upgrade command output:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libgeoip1 (1.4.7~beta6+dfsg-1) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libgeoip1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libisc62 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze3) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libisc62 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdns69:
 libdns69 depends on libgeoip1 (>= 1.4.7~beta6+dfsg); however:
  Package libgeoip1 is not configured yet.
 libdns69 depends on libisc62; however:
  Package libisc62 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libdns69 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisccc60:
 libisccc60 depends on libisc62; however:
  Package libisc62 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libisccc60 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisccfg62:
 libisccfg62 depends on libdns69; however:
  Package libdns69 is not configured yet.
```

.. continues

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgeoip1
 libisc62
 libdns69
 libisccc60
 libisccfg62
 libbind9-60
 liblwres60
 bind9-host
 libavahi-core7
 libdaemon0
 avahi-daemon
 libexif12
 libffi5
 libgomp1
 libgphoto2-port0
 libgphoto2-2
 libperl5.10
 libsensors4
 libsnmp15
 libhpmud0
 libieee1284-3
 libnss-mdns
 libossp-uuid16
 libpq5
 libv4l-0
 libsane
 libsane-hpaio
 libssh2-1
 python-gobject
```

dpkg --configure -a

```
Setting up libpq5 (8.4.8-0squeeze2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libpq5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libperl5.10 (5.10.1-17squeeze2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libperl5.10 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libffi5 (3.0.9-3) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libffi5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libexif12 (0.6.19-1) ...
```

.. continues

Suggestions are really welcome I really don't know what to do.

Michael.

Comment: Currently editing /var/lib/dpkg/info/lib.postinst removing the ldconfig, this seems to fix the problems when running upgrade. Please tell me if this is a no go I'm not experienced enough to know if I'm doing something really wrong this way.

Comment: Editing some files and running apt-get upgrade -f seemed to remove the errors. Dont know if it really fixed the editing i did :P

Comment: That `bus error` message is very troubling. I'd have normally attributed it to a hardware fault, but I'm not sure. Might be worth running memtest86 or other diagnostics on the system.

Comment: thx for the advice I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is boned in some very curious way.  If `ldconfig` is the cause of a post-installation script returning `135`, it's because `ldconfig` is dying with a SIGFPE -- a floating point exception.  That either points to a very curious bug in `ldconfig` (very unlikely) or some sort of latent hardware error (far more likely).

If you'd like to diagnose this problem further, you can try running `ldconfig` in a debugger and see what happens, but there isn't going to be a quick fix to this, and my money's still on a hardware fault.